# I Have a Function Loading a Value From a File, but It Isn't Working

Tags: python, variables

```
gold = 0
def load_gold():
  e = open('gold.txt', 'r')
  ee = e.readline()
  gold = int(ee)
load_gold()
```

In the file, the only information is

-1

The saving function works just fine, but whenever I reload and run the program, it resets gold to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gold` is declared as a global variable so if you want to alter it in your method you need declare is global in the method. Like this:

```
gold = 0
def load_gold():
    global gold
    e = open('gold.txt', 'r')
    ee = e.readline()
    gold = int(ee)
load_gold()
```

Comment: Advocating the use of `global` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the **scope** of your `gold` variables.

In the first line of your code you declare a variable named `gold`. This variable is global in scope. You create a new, separate variable, also named `gold` within your `load_gold` function. This variable's scope is only inside the function. It is not interacting with that separate, global `gold` variable, and it is destroyed once the function is finished running.

The following code would achieve your goal:

```
gold = 0
def load_gold(gold):
  e = open('gold.txt', 'r')
  ee = e.readline()
  gold = int(ee)
  return gold
gold = load_gold()
```

Further reading: [Global and local scope of Python variables](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html)